ActiveMQ Artemis journal recovery of unrouted messages after a disaster
I am trying to recover messages that were sent by an application to an ActiveMQ Artemis queue for a disaster related scenario. The scenario goes as such: broker1 is up and running talking to application1 and another application2 using JMS. Messages are routed from application2 to ActiveMQ Artemis to application1. During use application1 dies unexpectedly while the broker1 is still receiving messages from application2 resulting in a bunch of unrouted messages stacking up. Broker1 dies eventually and is restarted. Application1 is restarted as well. Application2 never dies. Then the broker1 comes up I want to recover the unrouted messages and replay them to application1. I am having problems with recovering the unrouted messages.
Things I tried:

Implemented AMQP broker connections (section 4.2 and section 5). Below is section 5 configuration to implement a store-and-forward mirror. This solution does not work. When replaying messages no unrouted messages are replayed.
I have ensured my messages have persistance="true" in the headers. I expected that the unrouted messages  would be journal-ed after being mirrored.
Confirmed that the ActiveMQ Artemis broker and it's mirror connect via the logs and the console

Expectations: I would assume if the messages are being sent between the broker and the broker's mirror that the messages would have been journaled. Therefore after a replay I would of had the messages replayed from application2 to application1 via the replay function in broker1. Is this assumption incorrect? The reason I used the replay function was that no messages automatically triggered upon broker1 coming back up.
Configuration for the mirror from broker.xml is below. The acceptors have the correct ports for the mirror and the original broker:
      <broker-connections>
         <amqp-connection uri="tcp://artemis-mirror:5674" name="mirror" retry-interval="1000" user="myuser" password="mypassword">
            <mirror>
            </mirror>
         </amqp-connection>
      </broker-connections>

Reverse mirror:
      <broker-connections>
         <amqp-connection uri="tcp://artemis-broker:5672" name="original" retry-interval="1000" user="myuser" password="mypassword">
            <mirror>
            </mirror>
         </amqp-connection>
      </broker-connections>

Journaling configuration:
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <journal-retention-directory period="6" unit="DAYS" storage-limit="10G">data/retention</journal-retention-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

I am using version 2.33 of ActiveMQ Artemis. I followed the disaster recovery example from the examples for the configuration above.

What you describe (i.e. a broker dying and being restarted) is not typically considered a disaster and does not require any special broker configuration to recover from.
As long as the messages sent from application2 to broker1 are sent to a JMS queue and are persistent then they will be reloaded from disk once broker1 is restarted at which point application1 can consume the messages from the queue that it missed while it was dead.
If you are instead using a JMS topic then you may need to either switch to a JMS queue or continue using a topic but with a durable subscription. With a durable subscription any persistent messages will still be available to the subscriber after it reconnects or after the broker restarts.
To be clear, there is no such thing as a "jms multicast queue." A "multicast queue" is a description of part of the ActiveMQ Artemis address model (which is 100% independent from JMS). JMS only supports queues and topics.
Also, your description of "unrouted messages" is not correct. Speaking in terms of the ActiveMQ Artemis address model, messages which are "unrouted" are those which are sent to an address and are not routed to any queue. When this happens the message is simply dropped. This is the expected behavior and is in accordance with publish/subscribe semantics. If you're using a JMS topic with no subscribers this is the expected behavior.

by default the delivery mode should be persistent with jms messages. I have explicitly put in that the delivery mode should be persistent to try to get the messages to journal, but the unrouted messages are not being journal-ed. only when the messages are sent via a valid connection to application1 are the messages being journal-ed.

What you're seeing is the expected behavior. Unrouted messages are not written to the journal by design. It sounds like maybe you're subscribing to a JMS topic which means you may need to either switch to a JMS queue or continue using a topic but with a durable subscription.

after implementing the durable subscription for a jms topic everything worked as expected.

Implementing a durable subscriber to the topic in question is what is needed to persist messages to remedy this problem.
